# Junit Test, I can't Mock a class with Diamonds Class<T>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock this method:

```
public ClassService{
     ClassResponseDTO method1(String var1, GenericDTO<ClassDTO> var2){
      //Code
     }
}
```

My mock:

```
ClassResponseDTO respRev = new ClassResponseDTO ();
ClassService classService = new ClassService();
when(classService.method1(any(String.class)
, ArgumentMatchers.<GenericDTO<ClassDTO>>any()))
    .thenReturn(respRev);
```

I'm getting a unnecesary stubbing error. Please Help.

Comment: is method1 a static function? If not `ClassService.method1(..)` is wrong. You should use a mock of `ClassService` not `ClassService` class itself

Comment: Sorry, I will update the post. ClassService not contains an static method.

Comment: are u still having the same issue? can u post the complete test code